# update statement in sql returns error must declare scalar variable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

The following is my code:

```
        Using myCommand As DbCommand = _Cn.CreateCommand()
            Try
                Dim sql As String = String.Empty
                If Not LUNA.LunaContext.TransactionBox Is Nothing Then myCommand.Transaction = LUNA.LunaContext.TransactionBox.Transaction
                    If cls.UserID = 0 Then
                        sql = "INSERT INTO Tabusers ("
                        sql &= " BenchID,"
                        sql &= " UserType,"
                        sql &= " UserName,"
                        sql &= " Password,"
                        sql &= " Status,"
                        sql &= " LastInTime,"
                        sql &= " LastOutTime"
                        sql &= ") VALUES ("
                        sql &= " @BenchID,"
                        sql &= " @UserType,"
                        sql &= " @UserName,"
                        sql &= " @Password,"
                        sql &= " @Status,"
                        sql &= " @LastInTime,"
                        sql &= " @LastOutTime"
                        sql &= ")"
                    Else
                        sql = "UPDATE Tabusers SET "
                        sql &= "BenchID = @BenchID,"
                        sql &= "UserType = @UserType,"
                        sql &= "UserName = @UserName,"
                        sql &= "Password = @Password,"
                        sql &= "Status = @Status,"
                        sql &= "LastInTime = @LastInTime,"
                        sql &= "LastOutTime = @LastOutTime"
                        sql &= " WHERE UserID= " & cls.UserID
                    End If

                    Dim p As DbParameter = Nothing
                    p = myCommand.CreateParameter
                    p.ParameterName = "@BenchID"
                    p.Value = cls.BenchID
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add(p)

                    p = myCommand.CreateParameter
                    p.ParameterName = "@UserType"
                    p.Value = cls.UserType
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add(p)

                    p = myCommand.CreateParameter
                    p.ParameterName = "@UserName"
                    p.Value = cls.UserName
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add(p)

                    p = myCommand.CreateParameter
                    p.ParameterName = "@Password"
                    p.Value = cls.Password
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add(p)

                    p = myCommand.CreateParameter
                    p.ParameterName = "@Status"
                    p.Value = cls.Status
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add(p)

                    p = myCommand.CreateParameter
                    p.ParameterName = "@LastInTime"
                    p.DbType = DbType.DateTime
                    If cls.LastInTime <> Date.MinValue Then
                        p.Value = cls.LastInTime
                    Else
                        p.Value = DBNull.Value
                    End If
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add(p)

                    p = myCommand.CreateParameter
                    p.ParameterName = "@LastOutTime"
                    p.DbType = DbType.DateTime
                    If cls.LastOutTime <> Date.MinValue Then
                        p.Value = cls.LastOutTime
                    Else
                        p.Value = DBNull.Value
                    End If
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add(p)

                    myCommand.CommandText = sql
                    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()


                    If cls.UserID = 0 Then
                        Dim IdInserito As Integer = 0
                        sql = "select @@identity"
                        myCommand.CommandText = sql
                        IdInserito = myCommand.ExecuteScalar()
                        cls.UserID = IdInserito
                        Ris = IdInserito
                    Else
                        Ris = cls.UserID
                    End If


                Catch ex As Exception
                    ManageError(ex)
                End Try
            End Using
```

I am getting the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@BenchID".

Comment: Just curious: Why aren't you also passing UserID as a parameter? Anyway, I'm not a VB guy, but it seems on first glance that you keep reusing `p` and replacing it. Why don't you just use `Parameters.Add` instead of housing each parameter in a variable for 3 nanoseconds?

Comment: For the first 5 parameters, they don't have a type. It's been over a decade since I've used VB, but I'd expect a type to given and not inferred. n fact you give types later on for other parameters..

Comment: At which command execution the error is thrown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a lot of trail and error and found answer to my trouble.  The answer is SQL server 2008 R2, which I am using, is not supporting named parameters.  That's why the error.

I had to change my code as under:

```
If cls.UserID = 0 Then
                        sql = "INSERT INTO Tabusers ("
                        sql &= " BenchID,"
                        sql &= " UserType,"
                        sql &= " UserName,"
                        sql &= " Password,"
                        sql &= " Status,"
                        sql &= " LastInTime,"
                        sql &= " LastOutTime"
                        sql &= ") VALUES ("
                        sql &= " ?,"
                        sql &= " ?,"
                        sql &= " ?,"
                        sql &= " ?,"
                        sql &= " ?,"
                        sql &= " ?,"
                        sql &= " ?"
                        sql &= " )"
```

Then it worked.  Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: SqlClient in .NET in conjunction with SQL Server 2008 R2 definitely supports the use of named parameters. The error is elsewhere.